# Uses-feature accelerometer in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

With the new  tag of the AndroidManifest, is it also possible to define my application requires an accelerometer? It seems to me only light sensor and proximity sensor are supported in the  tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />`

Is how I've declared it in my AndroidManifest, and I've yet to encounter anyone without an accelerometer with my app installed.

Comment: Seems like this got added recently, or I need a glasses upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features) there is a sensor feature for accelerator "android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"