# How to enforce accelerometer for android market apps?

Tags: android, google-play

How can I make sure that only users with an accelerometer sensor can download my app? Even better, how can I enforce the accelerometer to be of a certain accuracy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uses-feature accelerometer in the manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787269/uses-feature-accelerometer-in-the-manifest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make sure that only users with an accelerometer sensor can download my app?

Add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />` to your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) as a child of the `<manifest>` element.

> Even better, how can I enforce the accelerometer to be of a certain accuracy?

AFAIK, that is not possible, sorry.

Comment: For his second question, I would only add that he could make some kind of user-calibration panel for his app (but that's it).

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk, it still means that I will get users who have bad accelerometers that will purchase the app and then rate the app negatively and complain in the comments.  The app is a game which depends completely on the accelerometer.

Comment: @Gallal If there is a way to determine the accuracy from within the app (not sure there is, never used the accelerometer directly, but [getResolution](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) springs out, not sure what it returns for the accelerometer), you can check that value on app startup and warn the user if the sensor is bad. If that doesn't work, just put a big (I'd also say red, but that's not possible, unfortunately) banner in the app's description on the Market.