# Use accelerometer or not?

Tags: android

I am developing my first app for Android, and I wanted to know whether it is feasible to use the accelerometer.
I have heard that not all Android phones come built with an accelerometer. Is this true?
If it is true, then is there a way for a customer to know (via Android market) that an accelerometer is required to run the app?

Should I include the use of accelerometer or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787269/uses-feature-accelerometer-in-the-manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new phones usually all have the accelerometer but there maybe some without, you never know...

Anyway, you can set in the app manifest that your app require an accelerometer to run, this way it won't be visible from the market to the phones without.

Comment: Awesome, the last part is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**

No problem , you can do your app .. then when you publish it in Market .. say it's Required accelerometer :D !

**